# How can I map label values from a csv file to a numpy ndarray?

Tags: python-3.x, csv, numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

I have the following csv file:

```
id,label
1000,8
1001,1
1002,8
1003,1
1004,6
1005,1
1006,1
1007,2
```

I also have an image dataset which contains files like this:

```
1000_c.jpg
1000_v.jpg
1001_c.jpg
1001_v.jpg
```

and so on. For each observation I've got 2 images. I created an ndarray with the vertically stacked images so they become one image per observation instead of 2. My array has shape (1976, 15104).

I want to create an array that contains the label value corresponging to each vstacked image. The resulting array should of shape (1976, 2) one column for the id and another for the label. How can I do that?

Comment: As per my knowledge of ndarray(numpy). You can not do labeling in them. Maybe you should look at the data frame in pandas, they might help you with this.

Comment: hi @lifeisshubh i don't want to label the array, i want to create an array with the corresponding id and labels of the images in the first array. This should be really straight forward, the problem is that since i have vstacked my image data, i want to have in the labels array one label per 2 images, as the 2 images have the same label because the are part of the same observation. i don't know if im making this clear enough. But please ask me if you have any doubts